# Java get/set class not accessible in static context

Tags: java, class, getter-setter

I am attempting to create get/set class with Java. However, I am having trouble getting the data back from the class afterwards.

```
public class ARNStorage {
    String arnStorage;

    public String getArnStorage() {
        System.out.println("Got endpoint: " + this.arnStorage);
        return arnStorage;
    }
    public void setArnStorage(String arnStorage) {
        this.arnStorage = arnStorage;
        System.out.println("Saved endpoint: " + this.arnStorage);
    }
}
```

To store the String, I use the following (this works)

```
public void storeEndpointArn(String endpointArn) {
    ARNStorage endPoint = new ARNStorage();
    endPoint.setArnStorage(endpointArn);
    System.out.println("Storing endpoint: " + endpointArn);
}
```

However, to retrieve the String, I attempt retrieve it this way

```
public String retrieveEndpointArn() {
    String endPointArn = ARNStorage.getArnStorage();
    System.out.println("Retrieved endpoint: " + endPointArn);
    return endPointArn;
}
```

However, this returns a non-static method getArnStorage() which cannot be retrieved from a static context. My understanding a static context is that it cannot be called on something that doesn't exist.

Comment: You need to create an instance of the `ARNStorage` class if you want to use its non-static methods.

Comment: Why do I need to declare a new instance of ARNStorage to retrieve the value? The instance has already been created in the storeEndpointArn()

Comment: You don't.  But you do need to USE that old instance.

Comment: The thing is, if you say `ARNStorage.getArnStorage()`, it doesn't know which instance of `ARNStorage` you mean.  You could have a thousand of them for all it knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a `ARNStorage` local variable in the storing method and in the retrieval method, you don't use a `ARNStorage` instance but the class itself.
It makes no sense.
You should use an instance in both cases and the **same**.

To achieve it, the `ARNStorage endPoint` should be a instance field of the class and not a local variable if you want to reuse it from another method.

For example, you could have :

```
public class ClientClass{

    private ARNStorage endPoint;

    public void storeEndpointArn(String endpointArn) {    
        endPoint = new ARNStorage();
        endPoint.setArnStorage(endpointArn);
        System.out.println("Storing endpoint: " + endpointArn);
    }

    public String retrieveEndpointArn() {
        String endPointArn = endPoint.getArnStorage();
        System.out.println("Retrieved endpoint: " + endPointArn);
        return endPointArn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **keep hold and use the same reference to store and retrieve the string**.

```
ARNStorage endPoint = new ARNStorage();//endPoint is the reference to the object
endPoint.setArnStorage(endpointArn);

String endPointArn = endPoint.getArnStorage();//use endPoint to retrieve data
```

Comment: This will compile, but this won't do anything useful - he needs the *old* instance of the class that he previously stored something in.

Comment: OK, that looks better after the edit.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need `storeEndpointArn` and `retrieveEndpointArn` methods as `storeEndpointArn` and `getArnStorage` do exactly what you are trying to achieve via `storeEndpointArn` and `retrieveEndpointArn` respectively. You can try calling those `getters` and `setters` directly on instance instead of creating an object inside `storeEndpointArn` and setting the value (which does not do what you want it to do anyway).
2. As far as `static` and `non-static` methods are concerned, you can't call an `instance` method with a class name, only `static` methods can be called like this. Have a look at [this](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-vs-non-static-methods/) article for `static` vs `non-static` methods.